# trying to make a cogs loader doscord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a command which will load a certain cogs from cog folder.
I have followed a youtube tutorial
https://youtu.be/vQw8cFfZPx0
but I am getting some errors and I don't know how to fix it

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "#")

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@client.command
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}") 

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run('token')
```

and this is my cog file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.cog):
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    #event
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("bot is online")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")      



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Discord bot\cogs\ping.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Example(commands.cog):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

btw I am new to python so I may have done very silly mistake

Comment: I believe it's worth opening an issue in the CPython project for this error message. It is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`Cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog) is a class, and classes use the [CapWords convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names):

```py
class Example(commands.Cog):  # instead of class Example(commands.cog):
```

Answer (score 0):

`commands.cog` should be `commands.Cog`

The `c` in Cog has to be capital